# Is there a way to have FindInstance or Solve give only positive integer solutions?

Tags: equation-solving

I keep getting either negative or super long answers or super long negative answers in no particular order :\ ...
Is there a way to only ask for positive solutions?
(here we want 0 < x<(10^12+y) I tried using Assumptions but it didn't work :<

```
FindInstance[ 1/2 == x/(1000000000000 + y)*(x - 1)/(1000000000000 + y - 1), {x,  y}, Integers]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FindInstance[
 1/2 == x/(1000000000000 + y)*(x - 1)/(1000000000000 + y - 1) && 
  x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y}, Integers]
(*{{x -> 756872327473, y -> 70379110497}}*)
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! :D