# How to find an integer solution?

Tags: equation-solving

Given:

```
3*(c^3 - c^2*b - c*a^2 + a^2*b) == 
 a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3*(a + b + c)*(a b + a c + b c) - 3 a b c
```

Need to solve for all three variables as integers. Problem is to find one solution where all variables are positive.

Comment: please review my edit. Some of your formatting of the formula made it unclear and I'm not sure that I got it completely right.

Comment: @carl lange Gostei muito do seu canal no YouTube

Comment: @LCarvalho Obrigado pelas suas palavras gentis!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `FindInstance`.

```
f = 3*(c^3 - c^2 b - c a^2 + a^2 b) == 
  a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3*(a + b + c)*(a b + a c + b c) - (3 a b c)

FindInstance[f, {a, b, c}, Integers, 3]
```

> `{{a -> -130, b -> -130, c -> 65}, {a -> -1, b -> 0, c -> 1}, {a -> 1, 
>     b -> 0, c -> -1}}`

We can test the solutions out:

```
f /. {a -> -130, b -> -130, c -> 65}
```

> `True`

Comment: Nice work! Do you think it would be possible to have all variables positive? I meant to add this to the question/will edit.

Comment: Found this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74215/is-there-a-way-to-have-findinstance-or-solve-give-only-positive-integer-solution

Comment: @Dale Yes, simply add the extra constraints to the first argument in `FindInstance`: `FindInstance[{f, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}, {a, b, c}, Integers, 1]` However, in this case it does not appear that a solution exists.